# how do I can replace all the [span] [/span] in my website to <span></span> Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How do I can replace all the `[span] [/span]` in my website to `<span></span>` Using jQuery

I am looking for something like this

```
$('span').text().replaceWith($(this).text().replace(/[span]/, "<span>"))
```

Comment: You mean the results of user input, in textboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/\[span\]/g, '<span>').replace(/\[\/span\]/g, '</span>'));
```